# UIImagePickerController - how to save image to core data? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to save the image that I have picked from the ImagePicker and I want to save it in my CoreData. I create Attribute in my Entity with Binary Data type.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to convert `UIImage` to `Data`:

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
```

After that set this data to property in the `Entity` in the `perform` method of `NSManagedObjectContext`:

```
context.perform {
    entity.image = data
    // Save context
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't recommend you save UIImage to CoreData it's bad way. Just use https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage to cache an UIImage correct.

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea about Alamofire i'll try it. thanks for the for the help

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia,  please, make plus for my answer if it help you. =)

Comment: sure but I can't do it now due lower reputation.